# Google Kickstart 2021 Round A - K Goodness

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea, runtime-error

I have been trying to submit my code, but I am getting Runtime Error everytime. I am not able to point out the problem with my code. The code works fine on my computer, it just shows RUNTIME ERROR when I try to submit it.

I coded in IntelliJ.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class practice2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = 0;
        do {
            t = input.nextInt(); // number of test cases
        } while (t < 1 || t > 100);
        int n = 0; // variable to store length of the string
        int k = 0; // variable to store the goodness number
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            do {
                n = input.nextInt(); // string length
            } while (n < 1 || n > 100);

            do {
                k = input.nextInt(); // goodness number
            } while (k < 0 || k > (n / 2));

            input.nextLine(); // clearing buffer
            do {
                s = input.nextLine();
            } while (s.length() != n);

            s = s.toUpperCase(); // in uppercase

            int minOp = checkGoodness(s, k, n);
            System.out.println("case #" + (i + 1) + ": " + minOp);
        }
    }

    public static int checkGoodness(String s, int k, int n) {
        char[] sArr = new char[s.length()];
        sArr = s.toCharArray();
        int score = 0; int minOp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sArr.length / 2; i++) {
            if (sArr[i] != sArr[sArr.length - i - 1]) {
                score++;
            }
        }

        if ( score == k)
            minOp = 0;
        else
            minOp = Math.abs(score - k);

        return minOp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post more detail about the error, ps: what runtime error on which line?

Answer (score 0):

Make your class public and change it's name from "practice2" to "Solution".

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent runtime errors with submitting to an online judge are the incorrect name of the main class. You should check the requirements for Java and see what name for the main class should you use. Change "practice2" to that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`s = input.nextLine();`
Try
`s = input.next();`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int n,m;
        string s;
        int c=0;
        cin>>n>>m;
        int j=n-1;
        cin>>s;
       for(int k=0;k<n/2 && j>=0 ; k++)
        { 
            if(s[k]!=s[j] )
            {
                c++;
            }
            j--;
        }
        cout<<"Case #"<<i<<": "<<abs(m-c);
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't java... also there's no explanation to what the op's issue might be